# python pop() giving unexpected results

Tags: python

I have a nested list taken as user input for example the input below:

```
8
BUY Pride and Prejudice
BUY Anna Karenina
READ
BUY Hamlet
BUY Pride and Prejudice
BUY Anna Karenina
READ
BUY Hamlet
```

will translate to such a list below:

```
[['BUY', 'Pride and Prejudice'], ['BUY', 'Anna Karenina'], ['READ'], ['BUY', 'Hamlet'], ['BUY', 'Pride and Prejudice'], ['BUY', 'Anna Karenina'], ['READ'], ['BUY', 'Hamlet']]
```

so I'm supposed to write a python program which iterates through the nested list and whenever there is list whose content is 'READ', then I'm supposed to pop() the last element in the previous list immediately before the list whose content is 'READ'.
To be clear from the above input I expect the following output:

```
Anna Karenina

Anna Karenina
```

from the program I wrote:

```
no_of_actions = int(input())
my_stack = [input().split(' ', 1) for iterator in range(no_of_actions)]
to_be_popped = []
print(my_stack)
for inner_list in my_stack:
    if inner_list == ['READ']:
        read_index = my_stack.index(inner_list)
        print(my_stack[read_index-1].pop())
```

my output was not as expected;-

Anna Karenina

BUY

N/B: remember to use pop()

Comment: Adjusting the length of the list you are iterating over will always cause issues.

Comment: `read_index = my_stack.index(inner_list)` **gives you the first index**. Not the index of the current element you are iterating over in the for-loop

Comment: @user1558604 they aren't modifying the length of the list, `my_stack`, that they are iterating over.

Comment: So, you need to keep track of the index as you are iterating over `my_stack`, the easiest, idiomatic way is to use `for index, inner_list in enumerate(my_stack): ...`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga They are calling `pop` on the list they are iterating over. That is changing the length of the list.